# Can we have 2 Application running simultaneously on an android device?

Tags: android

What I wish to have is , one application is running on android main device and displayed on main device.
And second application is running on main android device and displayed on another display device connected to main device. This another display would have a touch screen.

**
What I mean is to have only one main android device . And another would be only a display device which is touch screen (Which will work as an accessory to main device). Both the application will run on main android device only the display would be different. 
One will be displayed on main device and another application will be displayed on the second display device.
Please let me know, if it is feasible or not. And if yes, what changes need to be done ?

Comment: not sure i understand . you mean 1 app per screen , where both screens are connected to the device? if so , just set the app to float , like the app AirCalc.

Comment: What I mean is to have only one main android device . And another would be only a display device which is touch screen (Which will work as an accessory to main device).
Both the application will run on main android device , one will be displayed on main device and another application will be displayed on the second display device.
Is it feasible or not ?

Comment: what is this second device ? is it just a monitor , or is it an android device ?

Comment: It is just a monitor, not an android device. It should be only used as a display.

Comment: ok , i've never connected my device to a monitor . it's just showing the same content as on the device , no?

Answer (score 4):

It somewhat is possible what you are thinking. Basically you would have one app running showing only on your main screen and one app running only showing on the connected (probably hdmi/mhl) monitor/display/tv.

The only thing is that the kind of api you need is not a general one for all brands of android devices.

Check this link for example for Motorola:

http://developer.motorola.com/docs/motorola-hdmi-status-api/